# AttributeError: Fedora instance has no attribute error

Tags: ros, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake ros_comm

AttributeError: Fedora instance has no attribute 'installers' I got this when I ran rosmake ros_comm. I installed ros as root on a glichy internet connection but I reran the install. So this is where I am at.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11230/attributeerror:-fedora-instance-has-no-attribute-error/) by [Reactor1967](https://answers.ros.org/users/1090/reactor1967/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-09-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This bug has been fixed in the code and will be available with the next update to ROS Electric.  For now, you should probably use ROS Diamondback if you are on Fedora.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1